# Yii Framework failed to insert data to a specific table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

After too many research online on how to insert data on a specific table I failed to find any beginning.

I have a table name called `yii_tst59` and it has the following fields: 
- `id`
-`idnum`
-`name`

I read some tutorial in `Yii` docs but those are existing tables.

What  I want to do is simple , insert data in `yii_tst59`.

what should I do in `/controllers/SiteController.php`, in the `/models` and in `/view`

I just need to know how to start, please help.

Comment: Are you using Yii or Yii2?

Comment: Do you have model for your table?

Comment: I am using Yii 2 with basic application template
from  `https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.6/yii-basic-app-2.0.6.tgz`

Comment: Bfcm, I dont have a model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it, if you want to do it with ActiveRecords is:

- Generate AR for the new table (you can do it manually or using gii - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)
- Use that model to populate the record and save it (see below)

  `public function actionTest(){ 
      $testModel = new Yii_tst59();
      $testModel->id = 1;
      ... set other variables...
      $testModel->save()
  }`

If you do not want to use active records you can insert it directly via SQL but I would not recommend it, specially if you're using Yii for the first times.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly insert your data using following format

```
$sql = 'Your insert query';
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```